# spymemcache - Does MemcachedClient has a built-in connection pool?

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I am using `memcached`, and use Java `spymemcache` to connect to it.

**My question is:**

Does `MemcachedClient` has a built-in connection pool?

Can I reuse instance of the class for concurrent operation on memcached, or I need to create a new instance each time I need it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Each MemcachedClient instance establishes and maintains a single
>   connection to each server in your cluster.
>   There is only one thread for all processing. Regardless of the number
>   of requests, threads using the client, or servers to which the client
>   is connected, only one thread will ever be allocated to a given
>   MemcachedClient.

More details can be found here https://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/wiki/Optimizations.

In one of our projects, to implement connection pooling, we initialized a List(size 50) of MemcachedClient and used one of them randomly while making a get or put call.

Comment: Why not to use Pool from Apache Commons instead of randomly selecting clients from preinitialized list?

Comment: @Ankur - How does it handle thread concurrency when multiple HTTP threads tries to use the same connection?